# ASP.NET Web API Exception filter - A way to get request url from HttpRequestBase?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-web-api

I've implemented a custom exception filter to my Web API. It is working as intended, except for one small detail...

In the following code sample, SaveToErrorLog saves exception details and tries to get the request url from context.Request.RawUrl. But context.Request does not contain the url that the API tried to serve when the exception happened. Is there a way to get the url when using an exception filter like this?

```
public class APIExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private HttpContextBase context;

    public APIExceptionFilter() 
    {
        context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);       
        if (actionContext != null && context != null)
        {
            facade.SaveToErrorLog(actionContext.Exception, context.Request);
        }     

        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {               
            Content = new StringContent(actionContext.Exception.Message),
            ReasonPhrase = "APIException"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look for uri in actionContext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the comment above by @emre_nevayeshirazi, you need to use the `HttpActionExecutedContext`. This gives you access to the request and then the required Uri.

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var requestedUri = actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri;
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: tiny typo: actionExec**u**tedContext

Comment: @Mark Jone. Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/qiOdmT